# Viewing a PDF with links on iPad

Tags: pdf, ipad

Are there any (hopefully free) iPad apps for viewing PDFs containing links?

For instance, I have a long PDF with a table of contents in the beginning containing links to later parts of the PDF. These links work when reading the PDF in Preview on my laptop -- when I click on the link for a specific section, the Preview jumps to that section.

Unfortunately, on my iPad, none of the PDF readers I've tried so far support this functionality. Are there any apps for the iPad that work like Preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked iBooks and it followed links to other parts of the document. It will also follow links to the browser if you allow it. Of course iBooks is free and there are a few ways to get pdf files loaded. It should be noted that navigation is far from full feature but it will probably improve over time.

Answer (score 3):

[GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8) is not free but supports linking.